# cURL Error 1: Unsupported protocol: https

Tags: curl, network-protocols

All,

I am trying to HTTPS POST a SOAP request via PHP's cURL wrapper methods but keep getting the following cURL error: Error 1: Unsupported protocol:  https, Any ideas why this is happening? The target URL is good and I'm able to reach it via commandline.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->apiURL);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
    'Content-length: '.strlen($SOAPRequest),
    'SOAPAction: ""'
) ); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $SOAPRequest);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: try after disabling SELinux (if running) and/or iptables

Comment: Also, where are you setting the remote certificate to use over https communication?   http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First check **phpinfo();**

If Curl is enabled in PHP as shown in the results of phpinfo() then

- The problem could be an extraneous space in the MySQL field containing the URL. The error isn't that the **"HTTPS" protocol is unsupported**, it is that **" HTTPS" (with leading space) is unsupported**.

Comment: Yeah, that was it - an extra space before HTTPS. Duh... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP was compiled without SSL support.

Comment: Our PHP has been compiled with SSL support