# curl: unsupported protocol(https) in CentOS6 - related with jansson

Tags: c, linux, curl, https, protocols

I am following jansson tutorial below.

https://github.com/akheron/jansson/blob/master/doc/tutorial.rst#id2

while I code like tutorial, I faced a problem.

this jansson thing uses curl library, and its curl_easy_perform() method

returns 1.

And console printed like this, "Unsupported protocol".

I already saw a solution(below link) and I could not find any extra space like that.

[cURL Error 1: Unsupported protocol: https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673154/curl-error-1-unsupported-protocol-https)

And now I do not have any clues of this problem.

If you have any good idea, please share with me =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line, run:

```
$ curl-config --protocols | grep HTTPS
```

If `HTTPS` is not printed, that is that the libcurl version your are linking to has not been built with SSL support.

In such a case, you must re-install it with SSL support turned on, e.g `yum install libcurl-devel` should do the trick. Re-verify and then re-build your sample code.

Comment: Thanks. you were right. there was no answer when I grep HTTPS. So I decided to use HTTP protocol which is absolutely supported.=)

Comment: I tried with above command line on my linux centos.Its showing me HTTPS but in phpinfo its not showing me in cURL's protocol. I am not getting this whay doing this. I restarted my server also. Pls give me your suggestion if you can . Thanks in advance.